# ComboBox which is bound to a db table should initially be blank

Tags: xaml

I have a WPF combobox control bound to a edm field in a database table.  This works fine except that it enters the first value in the control when it starts which is not wanted.  Heres the xaml

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbMeasure" 
          Width="104" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ddMeasureViewSource}}" 
          DisplayMemberPath="Measure"
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
          SelectedValuePath="Measure" 
          SelectedValue="{Binding Measure1}"/>
```

If I just hard code the control it doesn't put the first value in the variable.  Heres what that xaml looks like

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbMeasure" Width="104" Text="{Binding Measure1}">
        <TextBlock Text="one"/>
        <TextBlock Text="two"/>
        <TextBlock Text="three"/>
        <TextBlock Text="four"/>
</ComboBox>
```

What do I have to do to make the database bound combobox start with an empty value the way the textbox combobox does?  This is a problem as it puts the first value in the SelectedValue bound to a variable (Measure1).

The db table ddMeasure looks like:

```
RID    Measure
---    -------
1      One
2      Two
3      Three
4      Four
```

so "One" in put into the ComboBox selection and Measure1 variable is populated as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I found the solution to this.  You have to set the property IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem to false which I thought I had tried but I think I just removed that property and the default must be true.  So the xaml looks like

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbMeasure"
       Width="104"
       ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ddMeasureViewSource}}"
       DisplayMemberPath="Measure"
       IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"
       SelectedValuePath="Measure"
       SelectedValue="{Binding Measure1}"/>
```

Hope this helps others who try to find info on this type of binding.