# WPF ListBox binding when IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem=true

Tags: wpf, listbox

```
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
   ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}" 
   SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedGroup}"/>
```

On startup, before the screen displayed, my viewmodel had `SelectedGroup = Groups.First()` (and Groups contained several items).

I spent about an hour trying to figure out why my item was not being selected.  When I clicked (or pressed spacebar), then the selected item appeared selected, but before that, the item did not appear selected.

After I added `<ListBox IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem ="True">`, the app started working.

Question:  Can someone explain why this is necessary?  In other words, why would Microsoft have even made this an option?  Wouldn't I *always* want this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this example: [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875782/combobox-which-is-bound-to-a-db-table-should-initially-be-blank)

While using a ComboBox, it illustrates the idea: You don't want the first item automatically selected.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my actual problem was that my application was generating a different list of Groups each time the property was accessed, and so the value `SelectedGroup` property never equaled a value in the `Groups` property.

Groups was implemented with an iterator like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Group> Groups
{
   get
   {
      yield return new Group {Name="Todo"};
      yield return new Group {Name="Done"};
   }
}
```